# How can I build a custom class in NWN2?

Tags: neverwinter-nights-2

I would like to implement a custom class using the Neverwinter Nights 2 World Editor. What is the best way to learn how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can design your class using the [NWN2 Character Builder](http://nwn2db.com/)

Be aware, that creating a custom class requires a lot of manual work.
 Maria Caliban wrote together a nice [tutorial](http://nwn2forums.bioware.com/forums/viewtopic.html?topic=522669&forum=115#4552975) on the NWN2 Forums.